# How to find this Sum of floors

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

$$S= \sum_{n=1}^{m}(\lfloor k \rfloor) $$
$$k=((1+\sqrt{1+4n})/2)^2 $$

I want to know $S$ in terms of $m$

Comment: Well, $k = \frac 12 + n + \sqrt{n + 1/4}/2$ and if $k \le \sqrt n \le k+1$ then $k \le \sqrt {n+ 1/4} \le k+1$.